# Kafka replicator: ConsumerTimestampsInterceptor with kafka Streams?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

We are trying to replicate our offsets between 2 data centers. For a single consumer was really easy, adding only:

```
consumer.interceptor.classes=io.confluent.connect.replicator.offsets.ConsumerTimestampsInterceptor
```

Now we have an app that is using kafka-streams. And after tying multiple things we cannot replicate offsets as the one before.
For example we have tried as well:

```
kafka.streams.properties.consumer.interceptor.classes=io.confluent.connect.replicator.offsets.ConsumerTimestampsInterceptor
```

but no luck
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end Kafka Streams removes group.id parameter. However the replicator still needs it.

```
    override fun configure(configs: Map<String, *>?) {
        val newConfigs = configs!! + mapOf("group.id" to configs?.get("customgroupid"))
        super.configure(newConfigs)
    }
}
```

Then add this to your .properties file:

```
kafka.streams.consumer.customgroupid=${kafka.streams.group.id} # customgroupid is not removed
kafka.streams.consumer.interceptor.classes=com.myjob.mymodule.ConsumerTimestampsInterceptorConfigurator
```

Answer (score 1):

Try doing it in code rather than a property file

For example, the producer

```
config.put(
    StreamsConfig.PRODUCER_PREFIX + ProducerConfig.INTERCEPTOR_CLASSES_CONFIG, 
    ConsumerTimestampsInterceptor.class.getName()
);
```

Or, make sure `kafka.streams.properties` is the correct property prefix for creating all the StreamsConfig properties

Comment: I have:
ClassCastException: class io.confluent.connect.replicator.offsets.ConsumerTimestampsInterceptor
?

Comment: My answer doesn't do any casting, so can you edit your question with the full stacktrace?